# Does floor order matter?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'm occasionally granted Level Mover droids to shuffle the decks in my Tiny Death Star...but I can't tell if sorting the floors in some unknown way matters at all.  Other than using the lift to deliver people to different levels, I don't see any relevance to the position of each part of the <strike>tower</strike> Death Star.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is a bug or by design, but I found that the "Imperial Items Missions" seem to be based on the actual level, not the item type. So if you needed eg "10 Defense Grids", and you use a Level Mover to swap in the Interrogation level to where the Turbolaser laser was, that mission turns into "10 Rebel Secrets". So you can swap in levels that you already have high item counts for.

However, the reward for completing the mission appears to change accordingly (it would decrease in the above scenario as Rebel Secrets are easier to acquire).

NOTE: This has been changed so that the mission is attached to the item, not the level.  Moving levels no longer changes the requirements.

Comment: Has this continued to be true?  And, did you receive the missions that were previously offered to you after completing the original ones?

Comment: As mentioned by other posters, I reached the end of the missions. But until then, yes, it definitely remained the case, and they weren't "new missions" from what I could tell, they were the same missions (keeping the same counts for items you have already gathered) but just with different item types when you swapped the levels around.

Comment: Also (unrelated) for my last mission, I needed 6 Lieutenants, but I didn't have the appropriate level at that stage, although it turned out that I was in the process of building it. When I tapped on the mission in level 0, I was able to summon a Supply Officer to create a Lieutenant (despite not having the level built yet), and it offered me to "hurry it up" for zero bux. I did that the required six times, and I had my 6 Lieutenants. :-/

Answer (score 6):

Does the order of the floors matter? Somewhat. The higher the floor, the more credits you earn when you bring someone to it. Floors that will get a lot of traffic from arrivals will therefore earn you a tiny bit more if you raise them further up in your tower.

Re-ordering your floors can be useful. For instance, I like all my residential floors to be the even number floors. The reason is that when I want to speed up imperial objects being built, if an arrival wants an even number of floor, I know I can use them to speed up the imperial object without worry about them being useful to speed up a civilian order. But I could have easily put the residential floors together at arrivals, and just remembered that anyone travelling to floor 2 to floor 6 (for instance), can be re-routed to an imperial level with no worries about missing a chance to profit and speed up a shop order.

Comment: Whenever I get Mover Droids, I ''put the residential floors between Arrivals and the other floors.''  Full residential floors are worthless except to raise other floors and thus raise the tips I get delivering bitizens to the other floors.  Like StarPilot says, if floors 1-6 are residential (and, usually, full), I quickly dump their visitors DOWN to imperial floors.

Comment: I don't understand this, what factors into what floor a bitizen wants to go to?  I thought it was always completely random, as it seems that bitizens still go to full residential floors.

Comment: @StarPilot - Is there any way to determine which floors are a bigger draw to the bitizens?

Comment: Other than manually tracking? Not that I've found. 

What I've noticed when I had the same number of residential floors to shop floors is that shops get more traffic. May have just been the RNG quirk of the time, or may be a bias. Without doing some science on a few new games, I won't be able to determine which it is (code bias or simple RNG output).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of *by type*, I sort them by turnover time.  By turnover time, I mean the time needed to fully stock and sell a floor. For example, *Mos Espa Cafe* and *Workout Center* have short turnover times.

Until and unless I care to raise their ranks like crazy, floors with short turnover times need a lot of active management, so therefore I clump them together *to minimize scrolling*.

The game never tells you when stock needs ordering so you have to continually inspect all floors by scrolling from very top to very bottom.  Clumping often-needs-stock floors minimizes scrolling.

I place this clump close to Arrivals, because such floors are "<1 minute" more often and thus more often useless for incoming Bitizens.  I don't bring bitizens to "<1 minute" floors; I quickly dump them DOWN to imperial levels.

Comment: Also, *Celebrity* and *Big Spender* VIPs are best for floors with long turnover time.  I send them all the way up! :)

Answer (score 1):

The order of the floors, at this time, does not particularly matter - *unless you have a desire for organization of some sort*.  In the previous Tiny Tower game, you had the ability to move floors but for the cost of 1 Tower Buck.   That feature has been ported to Tiny Death Star, but they made it free if you wait for the random spawn of a mover droid.

Answer (score 1):

When I was playing Tiny Tower, I liked to have the floors organized by types, it was easier to find bitizens, but it was practically raining bux in there, here it's much more difficult to collect some...

In Tiny Death Star I personally like to gather all my residential floors just above Arrivals, so I know all the time, which appartments are full, where should I evict somebody to open a spot etc. It's good to always have at least one place rentable when people/ewoks come by the elevator, because, again, it's expensive to move them in instantly for bux.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with the strategy that you put the residential floors on the lowest levels. In particular, if someone wants to go to floor 2 or 3, which are currently full for me, I just dump them down to the lowest imperial level. Also, I use level movers to move whatever the "assignments" want most to the bottom, so that way it's easier to send the elevator there. I'm currently saving for the 499 buck elevator, so I'm not as concerned about credits at this point, but more on finding people, filling dream jobs, and catching rebels....

Comment: Good answer, but it is not really answering the question properly. The question is: Does floor order matter? If you can fix it up and clarify if it actually does something, that can help fix your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to use this format: 1 food level, 1 service level, 1 recreation level, 1 retail level, repeat until done. After that all the residential levels starting from the one you have less full. I observed that this way the visits are more balanced.

Comment: I don't believe there is ANY evidence that supports this. And, why would you care to balance your visits. Clearly you want more visits to your floors with more stock!

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm talking about my very own experience, you take it or leave it. Your second point is true that's why I also put my levels with more stock closer to the first floor but with the configuration I firstly mentioned.