# What's the point of imperial inventory?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I keep building these imperial levels and delivering supply workers to build items that show in my inventory screen (rebel secrets! security codes!) but I can't figure out why I would want to do that.

What do the imperial items do for me other than pile up in my inventory menu item?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These items are used to complete Imperial Assignments.

You can tap on the floor below your Arrivals floor (It is not named in the game, but some tips early-on explain its use) to see - and complete - the current assignment. These assignments require an increasing amount and variety of Imperial Items.

Comment: As the asker will presumably notice, these can be stockpiled for assignments you haven't gotten yet, so if you're waiting on the next Imperial level to complete your current assignment, you can still make items from existing levels to save for the next assignment that needs them.

Comment: Also refer to: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/143425/62360